# getting error while making a command to kick all members in a discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a command to kick all members from a discord server. Here is my code:

```js
client.on("message", message =>{
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "amstronglikeabullinapool")) {
  message.channel.send("ok i dont care")
  const user = message.member;
  
  var allMembers = message.guild.members
  

allMembers.kick()
message.channel.send("oki")

}

})
```

I am getting the error:

> allMembers.kick is not a function

Comment: is `allMembers` an array?

Comment: idk but I don't think so im new to discord.js

Answer (score 1):

You could try fetching all members first, loop through them and kick every member separately.

#### Example:

```js
const allMembers = await message.guild.members.fetch();
allmembers.forEach(member => {
   member.kick()
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
});
```

Comment: it is know saying "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: You may use `forEach` directly on it
```message.guild.members.forEach((member) => {
   member.kick()
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
});```

Comment: it is know saying "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Yeah you have to make the function async. Simply change the message event to this: `client.on('message', async message => { Your code here })`

Comment: You could make the callback async aswell `.forEach(async member => {})`, however asynchronous loops may cause issues

Comment: ty guys for the help

Comment: @Elitezen the `await` is outside of the loop

Comment: Well im getting no erros but it is not kicking anyone